# How do I record student grades in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, function, laravel-blade

I have an e-journal where I have already made a table with 10 grades And semester control [image: this one]
and implemented the function of adding a student to the database,my last goal is to implement the function of grading[image: this one]
The problem is that I stopped and do not know how to record grades for each student

E-journal page (journal.blade.php):

```
@extends('layouts.layout')
@section('title')Електронний журнал@endsection
@section ('content')
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-dark">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">ПІБ</th>
          <th scope="col">Тема 1</th>
          <th scope="col">Тема 2</th>
          <th scope="col">Тема 3</th>
          <th scope="col">Тема 4</th>
          <th scope="col">Тема 5</th>
          <th scope="col">Тема 6</th>
          <th scope="col">Тема 7</th>
          <th scope="col">Тема 8</th>
          <th scope="col">Тема 9</th>
          <th scope="col">Тема 10</th>
          <th scope="col">Семестровий контроль</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        @foreach ($students as $singleStudent)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $singleStudent->name}}</td>
            <td>{{ $singleStudent->mark1}}</td>
            <td>{{ $singleStudent->mark2}}</td>
            <td>{{ $singleStudent->mark3}}</td>
            <td>{{ $singleStudent->mark4}}</td>
            <td>{{ $singleStudent->mark5}}</td>
            <td>{{ $singleStudent->mark6}}</td>
            <td>{{ $singleStudent->mark7}}</td>
            <td>{{ $singleStudent->mark8}}</td>
            <td>{{ $singleStudent->mark9}}</td>
            <td>{{ $singleStudent->mark10}}</td>
            <td>{{ $singleStudent->semester}}</td>
        </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
<a class="col-3 btn btn-outline-info" href="/createusers">Додати Учня</a>
<a class="ml-4 btn btn-outline-info" href="/mark">Оцінювання</a>
@endsection
```

A page where there will be a grading system(mark.blade.php):

```
@extends('layouts.layout')
@section('title')Оцінювання@endsection
@section ('content')
<div class="row py-lg-5 ">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 mx-auto">
        <h1 class="fw-light text-white">Оцінити учня</h1>
<form method="post" action="/journal">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<div class="login-form-1">
    <form id="login-form" class="text-left" novalidate="novalidate">
        <div class="login-form-main-message"></div>
        <div class="main-login-form">
            <div class="login-group">
                <div class="p-2">
                    <div class="form-group text-white">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="p-2">
    <button class="col-4 btn btn-outline-info mr-3" type="sumbit">Готово</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
</p>
@endsection
```

Route file (web.php):

```
Route::get('/', HomeController::class);

Route::resource('journal', JournalController::class);
Route::get('createusers', [JournalController::class, 'create']);
Route::get('mark', [JournalController::class, 'mark']);

Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth'])->name('dashboard');

require __DIR__.'/auth.php';
```

JournalController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Student;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class JournalController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $students = \App\Models\Student::all();
    return view('journal', compact('students'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('/createusers');
    }
    public function mark()
    {
        return view('/mark');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $students = new Student();
        $students->id = request('id');
        $students->name = request('name');
        $students->mark1 = request('mark1');
        $students->mark2 = request('mark2');
        $students->mark3 = request('mark3');
        $students->mark4 = request('mark4');
        $students->mark5 = request('mark5');
        $students->mark6 = request('mark6');
        $students->mark7 = request('mark7');
        $students->mark8 = request('mark8');
        $students->mark9 = request('mark9');
        $students->mark10 = request('mark10');
        $students->semester = request('semester');
        $students->password = request('password');
        $students->save();
        return redirect('/journal');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $student = Student::query()->findOrFail($id);
        return view('journal', compact('student'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I find it hard to understand what you are trying to achieve exactly. Do you want to store the grades for a student?

It seems that in the `store()` function of your `JournalController`, you are storing a single student, and you have marks 1 - 10. You are also storing a semester.

Did you try and create a form and call the controller? Did any error occur?

I have a couple of general remarks that might help you with your question:

1. It seems you are storing marks 1 - 10 on the `Student` model, but these marks are probably changing every semester? I would advise creating a `Semester` model and a `Mark` model, where `Mark` has `BelongsTo` relation to `Semester`, and a `BelongsToMany` to `User`. I believe the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) can be very helpful.
2. You are using a `JournalController` to save a `Student` model. Is there any particular reason why you used this controller instead of creating a separate controller for Student (like `StudentController`)?
3. In the `store()` function of your `JournalController`, your are storing a unhashed password for the user. Passwords should always be hashed. You could use the [Hash facade](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/hashing#hashing-passwords) available in Laravel.
4. The `store()` function is also unprotected. But perhaps you are adding `Authorization` later.

Changing your question might make it easier for people to help you with your problem.

Comment: Landheeryes, it's a good idea, then I will have a page where you can select a semester and view student grades for that semester, so I need to make a separate table where student names will be stored so that when you add a student they add them to all semester page tables, and create more tables to store grades for each semester, right?

Comment: You can create a `Semester` and `Mark` model. The `Semester` model contains data of that semester. The `Mark` model stores a `student_id` and a `semester_id` (so you can identify what mark belongs to the student for the semester). In this way, you do not have to "hard-code" the marks 1 to 10. The `Student` model can simply contain student information (name, address, email, password etc).  Please check my other tips too and view the documentation. If you get stuck at any point, consider opening a new question.